# I'm working on a card game and I'm giving the users the options to draw, flip, or play a card. What's the code to play card option

Tags: java

```
switch(answer1){
     case "draw":
        player1.add(deck.get(0));
        deck.remove(0);
        break;
     case "flip":
        battlefield = deck.get(0);
        deck.remove(0);
        break;
     case "play":
}//End Switch
```

//This is switch number 1. There are 4 players but the code will be the same for all 4 players.

Comment: What means play? Explain how this should work :)

Comment: Play would mean playing a card that you have on your hand. The cards that you were distributed. Say I have a 5 Spades in my deck and I wanna play that card. Then I want to know how to code it do pick that card and "play it".

Comment: So play mean take a card in the player hand an put it in the battlefiled?

Comment: That is correct! :)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly It will be nice to send us your complete code. So I'm gonna assume that player1 and deck are Arraylist object. I gonna assume too that their are collection a a type Card.
Secondly are you really going to copy past your switch for the 4 players?

You have to tell us more specifically what do you mean by "play". Where did the card go? how does it affect the game?

In others improvement for your code I propose you to:
- Use a [Stack](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html) instead of and arrayList for the deck
- Make a collection of player so you can extend it
- Put your switch in a loop to use it for all players

You can start with something like this:

```
Card battlefield;
String answer;
Stack<Card> deck;
ArrayList<ArrayList<Card>> players = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Card>>;
for (int i=0; i<4; ++i)
    joueurs.add(new ArrayList<Card>);

// initilize var and process

for (ArrayList<Card> palyer : players) {
    answer = getAnswer();
    switch(answer){
    case "draw":
        player1.add(deck.pop());
    case "flip":
        battlefield = deck.pop();
    case "play":
        playCard(deck.pop());
    }//End Switch
}//end for
```